# "aluga-se casas" or "alugam-se casas"; "precisa-se de empregados" or "precisam-se de empregados"?

Tags: concordância-verbal

When should the verb agree with the object in this kind of sentence?  Quando devemos usar o verbo no singular ou no plural nesse tipo de frase?

Nâo é uma duplicata pois a resposta da outra pergunta não aborda a diferença entre os dois tipos de frase, a primeira quando o verbo é transitivo direto e a segunda quando transitivo indireto.  Quanto à resposta dada, de que só recentemente "alugam-se casas" passou a ser aceito como correto, eu discordo.  Já na década de 70, no Brasil, ensinava-se, nas escolas de segundo grau e nas faculdades de Letras, que a forma correta é "alugam-se casas".  Aquela resposta precisa ser revista e não aborda as diferenças que mencionei acima.